# Doing operands between Dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm doing a stopwatch and in need to display a timer when a event is ongoing until it ends. Admitting the event starts at 8pm and the current date is 9.30pm the stopwatch with show 01:30:00 and will keep ticking until the end_time arrives. Here is my code I need a way to give currentTime the value of currentDate- start_time

```
var currentTime = 0

func printTime() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let start_time = self.eventArray[self.clubId!]?.start_time
    let end_time = self.eventArray[self.clubId!]?.end_time
    self.currentTime = currentDate - start_time


    if(currentDate?.compare(start_time!) == .orderedAscending && currentDate?.compare(end_time!) == .orderedAscending)
    {
        if(timer != nil)
        {
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }else
        {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                self.currentTime += 1
                let hoursPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime / 60)
                let minutesPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime / 60)
                let secondsPortion = String(format: "%02d", self.currentTime % 60)
                self.sinceBandeauLabel.text = "\(hoursPortion):\(minutesPortion):\(secondsPortion)"
            })

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if `start_time` is `Date`, then you can use `currentDate.timeIntervalSince(start_time)`.